# Android Resources$NotFoundException when opening intent with WifiNetworkSuggestion

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, resources, android-settings

I'm encountering an issue when trying to open an intent with WifiNetworkSuggestion in my Android app. Whenever I call the `startOperation()` function, I get a Resources$NotFoundException with the following error message:

```
Drawable com.android.settings:drawable/ic_wifi_signal_0 with resource ID #0x7f080952
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040875 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f13059acom.android.settings:style/Theme.Panel, id=0x1030403android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Settings.Dialog, id=0x1030407android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Settings.DialogBase, id=0x1030438android:style/Theme.Material.Light.BaseDialog, id=0x1030237android:style/Theme.Material.Light, id=0x103000candroid:style/Theme.Light, id=0x1030005android:style/Theme], Themes=[com.android.settings:style/Theme.Panel, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
```

It seems to be related to a drawable resource `ic_wifi_signal_`0 in the `com.android.settings` package, but I'm unable to resolve it. The error mentions a failed attribute resolution with a specific TypedValue and theme information.

I'm using the `startOperation()` function to add WiFi network suggestions through an `ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS` intent. The code snippet I'm using is as follows:

kotlin
Copy code

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
fun startOperation() {
    val suggestions = ArrayList<WifiNetworkSuggestion>()

    suggestions.add(WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder().setSsid(ifeRougeWifiSsid).build())

    suggestions.add(WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder().setSsid(ifeAcWifiSsid).build())

    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_WIFI_NETWORK_LIST, suggestions)
    val intent = Intent(ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS)
    intent.putExtras(bundle)

    launcher.launch(intent)
}
```

I've checked that the `ifeRougeWifiSsid` and `ifeAcWifiSsid` variables are properly initialized.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!